# The row name is a decimal number

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I subset a dataset and this results in a dataframe with non-interger row name. Could you please the reason behind this phenomenon?

```
library(outbreaks)
df <- measles_hagelloch_1861[, 3, drop = FALSE]
df$disease <- 1
index <- sample(1:50, 50, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
syn_df <- df[index, ]
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: You probably have multiple rows with the same number, resulting from a trasnformation. In these cases, rownames will be suffixed by ordinal numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you sample with replacement, you end up with duplicate row names (you sample the same row more than once). Row names *must* be unique, so the `.1` is added to make them unique.

A simple example, repeating the first row of the `iris` dataset.

```
iris[1, ]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa

iris[c(1, 1), ]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 1.1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa

iris[c(1, 1, 1),]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 1.1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 1.2          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Generally, I'd suggest *against* relying on row names for anything... if you want to track observations, add some sort of ID column.